# Let $T$ be a surjective linear map such that $ \|Tx\| \geq \frac{1}{2017} \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$. Show that $T$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

***Problem:*** Let $T$ be a surjective linear map from a Banach space $X$ onto a Banach space $Y$ such that $$ \|Tx\| \geq \frac{1}{2017} \|x\|$$ for all $x \in X$. Show that $T$ is bounded.

I thought of proving by contradiction: saying that if $T$ is not bounded then $T$ is not continuous (since we know that $T$ is bounded is equivalent to $T$ is continuous), but it get me to nowhere.

Could anyone give me a tip or a solution for this problem? Thanks

Comment: Look at $T^{-1} \colon Y \to X$ and recall one of the _big_ theorems in functional analysis.

Comment: I haven't take a Functional analysis class, but from what I can see in a small chapter in Royden, are you referring to a Corollary to The Open Mapping Theorem which said that "Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be one-to-one and onto. Then $T^{-1}$ is continuous".?

Comment: Yes. But we apply it to $T^{-1}$, since we know that that is continuous, and deduce that $(T^{-1})^{-1} = T$ is continuous.

Comment: Next year, this exercise becomes harder!

Comment: @DanielFischer , I have been trying a similar problem myself, but my concern with this approach is that, the corollary require $T$ to be one-to one and I can't verify that from the statement, how do I check that.
If that is holds, then you'll end up with $||T^{-1}x||\leq 2017||x||$ as shown below by Lucas. Here, I believe you also need to show that $T^{-1}$ is one-to-one and surjective to conclude that its inverse $T=(T^{-1})^{-1}$ is continuous (the corollary), then we have boundedness of $T$. So how do we show for one-to-one condition  in both instances and surjectivity in the second part

Comment: @J.Kyei The existence of a $c > 0$ such that $\lVert Tx\rVert \geqslant c\lVert x\rVert$ ensures the injectivity of $T$ (since $Tx = 0 \implies x = 0$). The surjectivity of $T$ is explicitly stated as an assumption. Hence $T$ is bijective. And the inverse of a bijection is again a bijection, so we know $T^{-1}$ is bijective.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much, I am closer to understanding it fully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After all the comments made I have this, hope it is right:

Let $T$ be a surjective map $T : X \to Y$. It s obvious that $T$ is injective since $\|Tx\|=0$ imply $\|x\|=0$ therefore $T^{-1}$ exists and 
$$\|T  T^{-1}x\|=\|x\|\geq \frac{1}{2017} \|T^{-1}x\|$$ or
$$\|T^{-1}x\|\leq 2017\|x\|$$ which means that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

Now we are using The Open Mapping Theorem Corollary " Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be one-to-one and onto. Then $T^{-1}$ is continuous"

By this $T=(T^{-1})^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore $T$ is bounded.